# How to resolve (Error: Unsupported type 'uses-permission') in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml

Right now, I'm doing an mobile apps to capture audio and save it in the database, but I have an error in my codes. And I don't know how to resolve it. When I run the program, it will show :

**Error: Unsupported type 'uses-permission'**

And below are my code in AndroidManifest.xml and the error come from here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lenovo.androidaudiocapture" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lenovo.androidaudiocapture.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

The activity_main.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lenovo.androidaudiocapture.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Record"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STOP"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STOP PLAYING RECORDING "
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The strings.xml :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Android Audio Capture</string>
</resources>
```

and lastly, the MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.lenovo.androidaudiocapture;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlayLastRecordAudio,
        buttonStopPlayingRecording ;
String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
Random random ;
String RandomAudioFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
    random = new Random();
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(checkPermission()) {
                AudioSavePathInDevice =


    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                    CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + 
"AudioRecording.3gp";
                    MediaRecorderReady();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    });
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException {
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    buttonStopPlayingRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                MediaRecorderReady();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void MediaRecorderReady(){
    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
}

public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < string ) {
        stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.
                charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));
        i++ ;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
            String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, 
RequestPermissionCode);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] 
grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission 
Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
public boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            RECORD_AUDIO);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

I hope I can get positives reply.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the layout, strings.xml and the irrelevant Java code. There's too much code right now

Comment: @Zoe there is typing mistake in his manifest file while he is adding permission in manifest file

Comment: @NileshRathod I know. That's why I asked OP to remove the irrelevant code. (I'm not going to do it as I don't want to be suspected for vandalism). The point is removing the irrelevant code so this post later can be used to mark other potential posts with the same issue as a duplicate of this. If there is too much code it's harder to mark otehr posts as a duplicate later

Comment: @Zoe i agree with u my friend

Answer (score 0):

> there is typing mistake in your manifest file while you are adding permission in manifest file

**you should use this**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**instead of this**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The following permission does not exist(and it causes your error):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Use this one instead:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've already change it as you said, but it still error, the same error